# MySQL and Hibernate are not configuring

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm working on a spring boot project example and I have already created the database but when I configure the database, it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't give me an error though but when I execute the application, nothing shows on the console that I have added the hibernate properties.
I was expecting something like HHH000204:Processing PersistenceUnitInfo etc.
As a result of that, when I tried creating columns in table for the Employee entity it didn't work.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kessie</groupId>
    <artifactId>Springboot-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Springboot-backend</name>
    <description>Springboot Restful Web Services</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.kessie.model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

}
```

**SptingbootApplication.java with Main class**

```
package com.kessie;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;


@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootBackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Console after execution**

```
2023-01-12T01:36:34.051-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] c.kessie.SpringbootBackendApplication    : Starting SpringbootBackendApplication using Java 19.0.1 with PID 3832 (C:\Users\Koranteng K. Kessie\Documents\Spring boot\Projects\Springboot backend\Springboot-backend\target\classes started by Koranteng K. Kessie in C:\Users\Koranteng K. Kessie\Documents\Spring boot\Projects\Springboot backend)
2023-01-12T01:36:34.058-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] c.kessie.SpringbootBackendApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-12T01:36:35.390-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-01-12T01:36:35.400-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-12T01:36:35.400-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
2023-01-12T01:36:35.519-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-12T01:36:35.522-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1365 ms
2023-01-12T01:36:36.067-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-12T01:36:36.078-08:00  INFO 3832 --- [           main] c.kessie.SpringbootBackendApplication    : Started SpringbootBackendApplication in 2.574 seconds (process running for 3.094)
```

Comment: Well you excluded the auto configuration for a dataasource, so no datasource no JPA. Remove the exclude.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code, dependencies and configuration.

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This does exactly what it is meant to do, disable the configuration of a `DataSource`. If you have no `DataSource` there is no JPA as that will need a `DataSource` to connect to the database.

Remove the aforementioned line from your class.

There is another problem in your code, or actual your dependencies.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The scope `provided` means I use this dependency but yuo need not to include it as it is already part of the server/runtime I'm using. Which means it isn't on the classpath so no JPA dependencies are found and thus no JPA auto configuration will happen.

Remove the `<scope>` tag and it will be included.

Next your configuration is wrong. You have an illegal JDBC url in there as well as a non-existing Hibernate Dialect (it got removed in Hibernate 6).

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false
```

You have a missing `:` after `mysql` which leads to no JDBC driver being detected to handle the URL, leading to no `DataSource` being configured.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system?useSSL=false
```

Last, but not least, you also have a misconfiguration of the Hibernate dialect. The one you have doesn't exist anymore in Hibernate 6.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

The `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect` got removed in Hibernate 6. [Here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html) is the list of build-in dialects for Hibernate 6.1. You should be using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` as the other ones are deprecated and will eventually be removed as well.

**TIP:** instead of using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` you can use `spring.jpa.database-platform` to set the dialect.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

**NOTE:** You probably had this issue before and thus leading you down the path to exclude the JPA stuff (the `<scope>provided</scope>` and disabling auto config for the `DataSource`). This made the error go away but didn't fix it as it simply disabled stuff.

Comment: I've commented that line out and it's still not communicating to the database and hibernate is still not getting configured

Comment: Then you either didn't do what I told or you aren't showing the actual configuration and code. Or you might need to refresh your workspace.

Comment: You have another issue, the scope of `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is provided, remove the scope.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to. You were talking about the @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) inside the SpringbootBackendApplication.java right? I commented that out and reloaded the project but it's still not communicating with the database

Comment: See my other comment (and updated answer), you have an issue with your dependencies as well.

Comment: After removing the <scope> tag it gave this is what I got   "APPLICATION FAILED TO START
             ***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: Now this means it is working but you have some misconfiguration/missing dependency. Also please don't add error messages etc. in comments as those are totally unreadable. Nonetheless your first issue was resolved as it is loading now (you probably had this before hence the provided scope and exclusion which "fixed" the issue but not really as it disabled everything). But the problem is your configuration (as well) as the JDBC url is wrong, it is missing a `:` after `mysql`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251071/discussion-between-casparo-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Initially i had this error message that's why I added the @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) and this fixed it

Comment: It didn't fix anythign, it only disabled stuff, which probably lead to JPA complaining about no datasource, which lead you to mark the scope of provided.

Comment: It is now working after adding the colon after mysql. It gave me an error about the hibernate so I had to remove the InnoDB from the hibernate properties

Comment: YOu should be using `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` the others are deprecated (expanded the answer to include that one as well).

Answer (score -1):

```
 spring.jpa.show-sql=true

 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Add these lines of code to you application.properties it will print sql queries in formated form and let me know if it works or not

Comment: After adding the lines, the program executes perfectly but it's still not communication with the database

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>                                                                                                    Add this dependency as I can see you have added wrong dependency there is spelling error there

Comment: I have added the dependency but it still doesn't communicate with the database

Comment: can u tell me if there is any error

Comment: No please.... There is no error

Comment: send me your full code

Comment: I just added what prints on the console after execution to the post

Comment: as i can see there is no error on console then share your whole code so that i can try because in these shared file i cannot figure out any error

Comment: He excludes the datasource configuration, adding additional dependencies and properties is useless.

Comment: Everything I've done so far is what I've shared

Answer (score -1):

*-- change the MySQL dependency in pom.xml In ur MySQL dependency artifactId is **MySQL-connector-j** it's not fulfilled Add Datasource driver in ur application properties like check the below answer  --*

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 

-- application properties-- 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver   
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee_management_system
spring.datasource.username=root  
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: The application executes but it's still not communicating with the database and hibernate is not getting configured

Comment: He excludes the datasource configuration, adding additional dependencies and properties is useless.